# Regarding Templates in c++

Tags: c++, oop, templates

this might be a silly question but it's very important to me , tomorrow is my final exam in Object-Oriented C++ , anyways my teacher said something very important (That I can't remember) about when I am supposed to specify variables or data types when I am making an object, it's something like < int , int , int , double , int > .. everything on the left side must be the same type or the opposite I can't remember it, please if anyone got the idea about what I am talking about PLEASE help me <3 am desperate

Editing:
ugh I'm very sorry but I am really scared from this exam and this thing is important :( anyways when I am making an object from a class that has templates it goes like this Class <.int, int, double.> obj1 , right ? these data type in the middle, there's a rule about them that says if the first type is integer then everything on it's right or left must be the same type, or something like that, that's what I can't remember

Comment: Please take some time to [format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and tell us a bit about the context. E.g. *everything on the left side* the left side of what?

Comment: The only thing i can think of that you might be referring to, is that (for example) a `foo<long>` can't be assigned to a variable of type `foo<int>`; even though there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`, the two template instantiations are unrelated.  The types have to match exactly.

Comment: ugh I'm very sorry but I am really scared from this exam and this thing is important :( anyways when I am making an object from a class that has templates it goes like this Class <int, int, double> obj1 , right ? these data type in the middle, there's a rule about them that says if the first type is integer then everything on it's right or left must be the same type, or something like that, that's what I can't remember

Comment: Class templates can be used to let the compiler create classes, during the compilation of the program. You can create *different* classes by using *different* arguments. The number of arguments depends on the class template. For example, there's the `list` class template in the C++ Standard Library. You can use it e.g. to make a class *list of `int`s*. This class is created automatically when you refer to it. Its name is written as `list<int>`: the name of the class template plus the arguments wrapped inside `< >`. When you write `list<int> my_object;` you create an instance of this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class template declaration consists of a *name* and the *template parameters*.  The template parameters come first, and are written within angle brackets, like this:

```
template <typename Foo, typename Bar>
class Gizmo
{
};
```

At this point, `Foo` and `Bar` aren't real types -- they are placeholders for real types you will provide when you instantiate the `Gizmo`.

Instantiating a class template starts with the class name, followed by `<`, and then a comma-seperated list of template parameters, followed finally by a `>` and your variable name:

```
Gizmo<int, double> myGizmo;
```

---

> these data type in the middle, there's a rule about them that says if
>   the first type is integer then everything on it's right or left must
>   be the same type, or something like that, that's what I can't remember

No, there is no such rule.  Any of the template parameters above could be any type.  The following are all legitimate:

```
Gizmo<int, double> g1;
Gizmo<int, std::string> g2;
Gizmo<std::string, int> g3;
Gizmo<double, char> g4;
```

What you might be thinking of is *default parameters*.  With **class templates** you can specify some defaults for the template parameters:

```
template <typename Foo=int, typename Bar=double>
class Gizmo
{
};
```

However, if you do specify a default template parameter, then all subsequent template parameters must also have defaults.  So this is OK:

```
template <typename Foo, typename Bar=int>
class Gizmo
{
};
```

...but this is not:

```
template <typename Foo=int, typename Bar>
class Gizmo
{
};
```

because there is a default for `Foo`, but not for `Bar`.

Comment: Note that `typename` could be substitued with `class` above -- the two are identical.

Comment: Thank you so much, The default template parameter rule is what I'm trying to remember and I got it confused with something else , Thank you so much you just saved me as my exam is in 45 minutes ..
Also I am very sorry everyone because my question was confusing .